# Predicting a single PNG image using a trained TensorFlow model

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning

```
import tensorflow as tf
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape = (28,28)),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation = 'relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(10)
])
```

This is the code for the model, which I have trained using the mnist dataset. What I want to do is to then pass a 28x28 png image to the predict() method, which is not working. The code for the prediction is:

```
img = imageio.imread('image_0.png')
prediction = model.predict(img, batch_size = 1)
```

which produces the error

```
ValueError: Error when checking input: expected flatten_input to have shape (28, 28) but got array with shape (28, 3)
```

I have been stuck on this problem for a few days, but I can't find the correct way to pass an image into the predict method. Any help?

Comment: Seems your `image_0.png` is an RGB, and not a greyscale one (but still, it should be `(28, 28, 3)`, not `(28,3)`).

Answer (score 2):

Predict function makes predictions over a batch of image. You should include batch dimension (first dimension) to your img, even to predict a single example. 
You need something like this:

```
img = imageio.imread('image_0.png')
img = np.expand_dims(img, axis=0)
prediction = model.predict(img)
```

As @desertnaut says, seems you are using a RGB image, so your first layer should use **input_shape = (28,28,3)**. Therefore, **img** parameter of predict function should have (1,28,28,3) shape.

In your case, **img** parameter of predict function has (28,28,3) shape, thus predict function took the first dimension as number of images, and could not match the other two dimensions to the **input_shape** of the first layer.